# IIS handles request much longer when request originates from another computer and returns HTTP 200 and text

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, iis, iis-7

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application I have two very simple controller actions one of which returns `ContentResult` with a short piece of hard-coded text and another one returns `HttpStatusCodeResult` with code 403.

The application is deployed, then a pack of requests is sent to the routes served by that controller actions several times from the same computer, then an equivalent pack of requests is sent to those routes from another computer. No configuration changes are performed in between, application pool is not restarted - nothing like that.

I review the IIS logs and see that `time-taken` (the time the request spends inside the web server and not including any network latencies, DNS lookups, etc) is very different depending on whether the request was sent from the same computer or not and also depending on which of the actions was called. If it's from the same computer `time-taken` is around 15 milliseconds for both actions. If it's from another computer `time-taken` is around 260 milliseconds for the action returning `ContentResult` and around 100 milliseconds for the action returning 403.

Clearly there's a dependency on whether any content is returned in the response body when the request comes from another computer.

My code doesn't have any explicit logic that changes how requests are handled depending on their origin and result.

What might cause the timing difference?

Comment: Is windows authentication being used?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Do you mean NTLM? No, web.config only enables Forms authentication but I'm not sure it doesn't kick in at some point.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I tried removing `WindowsAuthentication` module by editing `web.config` - no changes in timings.

Comment: have you used any browser's developer tools to check which part of your request is taking the longest time?

Answer (score 0):

So a request from localhost is quicker than a request from a remote computer. That makes perfect sense - the localhost doesn't have to do a network request out to the network, find a remote host, send the request over the network and then wait for a response.

Having said that - if your application is taking 15ms locally and 260ms on even a relatively close network, then it's slow :).

Comment: `time-taken` is in IIS logs on the server side, it's time that the web server needs to serve the request, that doesn't include the network latency, DNS lookups, etc, just what happens in the web server itself.

Comment: It doesn't include time spent reading from the incoming buffers?

Comment: Reading from buffers is definitely not a problem - timing depends even on which HTTP code the application returns.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944884 time-taken can include network time under some circumstances.